# getClass() prints binary format while using constructor in Enum

Tags: java, enums, classname

I am learning the various options that an enum can provide to us. I have learnt about constructors, methods and overriding methods in it.

The code samples are below.

I have one question though.

In this case, `getClass()` returns class `enumData.WeekEnumElaborate$1`, `enumData.WeekEnumElaborate$2` and so on until `enumData.WeekEnumElaborate$8`

But, when the enum is a simple one, with just constants declared, `getClass()` returns `enumData.WeekEnumElaborate`.

Kindly explain me this binary notation.

Here is a enum that I have defined.

```
package enumData;

public enum WeekEnumElaborate {
    SUNDAY("SUN") {
        public String getDescription() {
            return this.getShortForm().concat(" Funday");
        }
    }, 
    MONDAY("MON") {
        public String getDescription() {
            return this.getShortForm().concat(" Moot");
        }
    };

    private final String shortForm;

    private WeekEnumElaborate(String shortForm) {
        this.shortForm = shortForm;
    }

    public String getShortForm(){
        eturn this.shortForm.toLowerCase();
    }

    public abstract String getDescription();
}
```

And here is a class that I am testing.

```
package enumData;

public class TestWeekEnumElaborate {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    WeekEnumElaborate[] days = WeekEnumElaborate.values();

    for (WeekEnumElaborate day : days) {
        System.out.println(day.name());
        System.out.println(day.getClass());
        System.out.println(day.getDeclaringClass());
    }

}
```

}

Comment: **Please** don't write code like that.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Oopsie doopsie... edited it

Comment: It's not binary code. It's just the way Oracle Java gives names to synthetic members.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Okay. I wanted to know why is it there when constructors are used and not in the other case?

Comment: Still, it's an interesting question, and one I've not seen before. 1+

Comment: @RealSkeptic Thank you; but an initial search didn't get me the duplicate. How do I even use the right keywords?

Comment: Well, I admit it was a tricky one, as attested by the fact that you got answers from reputable users who usually search for duplicates first. Don't feel bad about it - I knew what to search for because I knew the answer. It's important to have questions like yours connected to the duplicate so that the next person will find it more easily!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently defining anonymous inner classes in your `enum` definition, which is the part I was referring to when I asked you to **not** write code like this. To elaborate, the way I would implement your original `enum` would be something like

```
public enum WeekEnumElaborate {
    SUNDAY("SUN", "Funday"), MONDAY("MON", "Moot"), TUESDAY("TUE", "Terrible"), 
    WEDNESDAY("WED", "Weed"), THURSDAY("THUR", "Terrific"), FRIDAY("FRI", "Fairy"),
    SATURDAY("SAT", "Jollyday"), R$00("R$00", "RX100 Day");

    private final String shortForm;
    private final String description;

    private WeekEnumElaborate(String shortForm, String description) {
        this.shortForm = shortForm;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getShortForm() {
        return this.shortForm.toLowerCase();
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return new StringBuilder(getShortForm()).append(' ').append(this.description).toString();
    }

    public String getFurtherDescription(String desc) {
        if (this == MONDAY) {
            return "I do not want to work on this day!!!!";
        }
        return getDescription();
    }
}
```

No anonymous classes required, and it is significantly shorter and easier to reason about.

Comment: Okay. Anonymous classes!!!  I was following an example from a blog which stated that using such methods in each defined constant is better than using a switch. I wonder if I misinterpreted it. btw, I learnt that even my exercise code could be cleaner too.

Comment: @Sara The blog writer is making an opinionated statement, my `if (this == MONDAY)` is *equivalent* to a `switch` (but I would prefer an `if` to a `switch` myself, but now we're strictly in the realm of opinion and *better* becomes subjective).

Comment: https://schneide.blog/2010/12/13/avoid-switch-use-enum/  So, I don't have to follow that? I know it is opinionated; but, if I implement in my project, will it be considered as a bad practice?

Comment: No switch or if else cascade here, and writing code like you initially posted is **definitely** a bad practice.

Answer (score 4):

When you give an enum different behaviour to the outer enum class, you are effectively defining an anonymous static inner class which is a subclass of the base enum class.

The names of these nested classes are named same way anonymous inner classes are named. Ie outer class + $ + counter.

This allows each enum to have different method implementations for the same signature.